# How to render a perfect pdf document usign custom field (of variable length) on a docusign document?

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to know if there is a way to fill in a docusign template with values while keeping a pixel perfect format and avoiding blank spaces or overwriting on existing characters.

For example :
"This NDA is between person1 and person2 and is expring on the 12/10/2022"
Person 1: John doe
Person 2: Mr Johny Dowerty Mc Carthy

How can Docusign perfectly fit the names in the sentence without overwriting or without being too below or too above?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create the entire document dynamically. There are many PDF generators available. Or my recommendation is to use HTML as the source for DocuSign.

Here's a [live example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=HTML%20responsive%20credit%20card%20form%20with%20smart%20sections) that uses HTML as a source document. The example also uses "Smart Sections" to enable a more dynamic document signing experience.

Comment: Thank you Larry. Since the template won't be handled by DOCUSIGN, what tool would you advise to create and update easily the html templates? Non developpers should be able to easily edit it. Thanks again

Comment: DocuSign's CLM package can "pour" text into a template. The templating systems that I've used have all been directed towards developers or technical users. So it depends on the technical expertise of the people who need to update the templates. Eg liquid templates, handlebar templates, etc